# Angular JS Phone Cat app

Tags: angularjs, shared-hosting

I am trying to learn Angularjs, I downloaded sample from [AngularPhoneCat.](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

This AngularPhoneCat App is successfully running in my local host.

I just want to learn how to upload this in my shared hosting, can someone help me with this?

I am using Shared Linux hosting:
Platform Type: Debian
MySQL Version: 5.5.44
Perl Version: 5.8.8
PHP Version: 5.5.22

Answer (score 0):

Well, the root of your angularJS application is everything that is inside your angular-phonecat/app folder. So you want to upload this in your shared hosting www.

Comment: I tried this already which is not working check [link](http://websensepro.com/angular-phonecat/app/)

Comment: Can you post some of your code ? Especially what is going on in your index.html.